# JSON Array Swift send using Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to send an array of JSON object which I need to update object on my server. I need the array for params request.
This is my construction of array I need in order to update server object value:

```swift
[{
    "propName":"number", "value":numberValue
}]
```

Here is what I am trying to make in Swift :

```swift
let params = [
  { "propName":"number", "value":numberValue },
  { "propName":"address", "value":addressValue },
  { "propName":"notes", "value":notesValue },
  { "propName":"latitude", "value":latitudeValue },
  { "propName":"longitude", "value":longitudeValue}
] as [String: Any]
        
let updateParkingSpotRequest = AF.request(URLs.MarkParkingSpotAsAvail(parkingSpotId: parkingSpotId), method: .patch, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: nil, interceptor: nil, requestModifier: nil)
```

But it doesn't work since it cannot convert this form of data, XCode says: "Cannot convert value of type '[() -> String]' to type '[String : Any]' ". How can I get that format of Data which server needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the initializer like this:

```
let params = [
  [ "propName": "number", "value": numberValue ],
  [ "propName": "address", "value": addressValue ],
  [ "propName": "notes", "value": notesValue ],
  [ "propName": "latitude", "value": latitudeValue ],
  [ "propName": "longitude", "value": longitudeValue ]
] as [[String: Any]]
```

i.e. params is an Array of Dictionaries of String to Any.

Answer (score 0):

The `parameters` parameter is a type of `[String: Any]` in Alamofire. So you need to create a parameter dictionary.

So assume that you have a list of `Data` models, you can create the `params` like below;

```
struct Data {
    var propName: String
    var value: Any
}

let values: [Data] = [
    Data(propName: "number", value: numberValue),
    Data(propName: "address", value: addressValue),
    Data(propName: "notes", value: notesValue),
    Data(propName: "latitude", value: latitudeValue),
    Data(propName: "longitude", value: longitudeValue)
]

let params: [String: Any] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: values.map{ ($0.propName, $0.value) })
```